# URL rewriting - Follow my rules and leave physical files alone

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Noob in mod_rewrite here...I'm developing a new site and using mod_rewrite.

**The problem is, when I activate my rules in .htaccess, my links to CSS files and images become unreadable.**

For example, I had this:
http://www.dico2rue.com/dictionnaire.php?idW=675&word=Resto-basket
That I transformed to this:
http://www.dico2rue.com/dictionnaire/675/Resto-basket

I know it's probably because the browser is looking for the CSS file in the
http://www.dico2rue.com/dictionnaire/675/css/general.css instead of the base directory, but **I was hoping there was a way to to leave physical files alone, and only parse other URLs** in order to avoid full paths (which apparently slows down downloas speed...?...).

thanks.

Comment: Can you provide your rules please? Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add these lines to check if it's not a file or directory right before the rewrite rules

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Comment: Testing.  I'll ket you know how it goes.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This problem doesn't have anything to do with mod_rewrite; you just need to provide a valid URL to your CSS file in the src attribute of your link tag. The relative URL you probably want to use is "/css/general.css". See the [relative URL rfc](http://www.w3.org/Addressing/rfc1808.txt).

On another note, your thinking about mod_rewrite might be a little off. In your example you are actually providing a resource in the /dictionnaire/675/ path of your server. The fact that you are using mod_rewrite to do it instead of some other method makes no difference.